# Sorting Linked list : random or nearly sorted?

Tags: sorting, linked-list

i have a linked list and i want to check whether its nearly sorted or random? Can anyone suggest how to do that??

Right now what i am trying to do is run upto half of list and compare adjacent elements to check whether given list is nearly sorted or otherwise. But difficulty is that this method is not full proof and i want something concrete.

Comment: You haven't defined what "nearly sorted" means.

Comment: nearly sorted means that there aint much elements to sort. almost all the elements are in their right position.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have 100 item then the scale will be out of 100. (Score of how much the list is sorted.) If you have all the list sorted you have a score of 100. If the list is sorted in backwards then you have a 0 score. You will be checking each of the adjacent and decide if the pair is sorted or not (0th and 1st, 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd and so on). Therefore you will have a scale between 0 and 100 (or the linked list size for your case). There are a lot of heuristics about the "sorting scale" but this might be one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to involve the amplitude of your data you can do (Python3):

```
import random    
l = [random.random() for x in range(100)]
s = 0
for i,x in enumerate(l[0:50]):
    s += l[i+1] - x
print(s)
```

if you'd rather just look at how many values are sorted, replace the `s+=` line with

```
    s += 1 if l[i+1] > x else 0
```